# FormulaR1C1 does not work

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Dim lastrow As Double
Dim lastrowX As String

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lastrowX = "X2:X" & lastrow
Range(lastrowX).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]=RC[-19],RC[-15],"""")"
```

The problem is that instead of working formula, it gives me the following:

```
=IF(RC[-4]=RC[-19],RC[-15],"""")
```

Why excel does not want to "convert" RC into reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the cell formatting is not allowing the formula to be considered as real formula.  Since the cell may be formatted as Text.

Replace the below line of code

```
Range(lastrowX).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]=RC[-19],RC[-15],"""")"
```

With

```
With Range(lastrowX)
    .Clear
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]=RC[-19],RC[-15],"""")"
End With
```